# Filter the lastest date in r

Tags: r, filter

I wonder if there is a way to filter the lastest date of the factor and return the amount that match with it.

Here is my dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast"), levels=c("Breakfast")), date=c("2020-01-20","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-02-10","2020-02-11","2020-02-12"),
  total_bill = c(12.7557,14.8,17.23,15.7,16.9,13.2)
)
```

We know that the lastest date is `2020-02-12` and I dont want to write the specific filter like `filter(date %in% "2020-02-12")` if the dataframe has been update a day after like `2020-02-13` It will be hard to filter with specific date.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See the `which.max()` function

Comment: can you apply it with this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `subset`

```
subset(transform(dat, date = as.Date(date)), date == max(date))
```

Comment: Can you help this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61806711/removing-duplicated-column-characters-of-dataset-in-r?noredirect=1#comment109322900_61806711

Comment: I updated the post in case you dont understand my question

Comment: @Ben10 do you need `y %>%  group_by(jhu_ID) %>% slice(1)`

Comment: Yes that is right but can we avoid using groupby because when I put it in it group by. It divided  some names not country and some names of country but yeah it appear one time each. Can you verify it and answer in my post. I just want it in order of alphabets. Thanks

Comment: @Ben10 You can use `y %>% filter(!duplicated(jhu_ID))` or `y %>% distinct(jhu_ID, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: It is nearly what I needed I just want it in the order alphabet the country start with name ```A``` until ```Z```

Comment: @Ben10 For that you can just do `arrange(jhu_ID)` after the `distinct`

Comment: Can you post the answer in my new post then I can test and vote it up

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lubridate::ymd` to transform your `date` column from character to date, and then use `filter` and `last` to only select the row that contains the last date in the 
dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  filter(date == last(date))
```

Comment: If I have two factors up and then I want to sum those factor with the highest date what should I get here?

Comment: @Ben10 I would suggest making a new question, since that seems like a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

See `?which.max` to get started:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast"), levels=c("Breakfast")), 
  date = c("2020-01-20","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-02-10","2020-02-11","2020-02-12"),
  total_bill = c(12.7557, 14.8, 17.23, 15.7, 16.9, 13.2)
)

which.max(dat$date)
#> [1] 6

dat[which.max(dat$date), ]
#>        time       date total_bill
#> 6 Breakfast 2020-02-12       13.2
```

Alternatively, you can use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  filter(date == max(date))
#>        time       date total_bill
#> 1 Breakfast 2020-02-12       13.2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If I have two factors up and then I want to sum those factor with the highest date what should I get here?

Comment: @Ben10 -- This seems like a new/different question. I would recommend reading about how to ask a great question -- also _try_ some things first and use the search function. Chances are someone has already asked a question like that. You are also likely to learn more quickly if you try things out for yourself, get stuck, and then have a breakthrough.

Comment: Thank for your advice I am new to stackoverflow that is why. I just want to sum at lest two factors with the latest date but I got stuck with the combination of the clause ```mutate```  ```summarise```