# Removing duplicated column characters of dataset in r

Tags: r, duplicates, character

I am new to r and I have problems with removing duplicated characters.

Here is my code:

```
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eparker12/nCoV_tracker/master/input_data/coronavirus.csv")
y <- read.csv(text = x)
z <- duplicated(y$jhuID)
```

I tried something like z <- ... but it did not work.
For the column `jhuID` in the dataframe it is the class `character` but there are many name of countries that repeat multiple times and my goal is to delete those duplicated name of country and make sure that it remain only one time with the same class `character`

For example if I view data by `y$jhuID`, I will see all the names of the country that appear multiple time. I want new dataframe for example `z` when I view `z$jhulD` I will see the name of country appear only one time each.

Any help for this would be much appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Comment: What trouble are you having? What code did you try? Something like `y = y[!duplicated(y$jhuID), ]`?

Comment: I updated what I have tried

Comment: Your method did not work can you verify it?

Comment: Can you add sample data and sample result you expect? Few observations of actual data will help.

Comment: Okay. For example if we view data by ```y$jhuID```, I will see all the names of the country that appear multiple time. My goal I want new dataframe for example ```z``` when I view ```z$jhulD``` I will see the name of country appear only one time each

Comment: I get 18 columns but none of them are called jhuID. There's one called `country`

Comment: sorry updated the post

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: You are repeating what you already said. You need to provide some sample values of input y$jhuID and output that you expect.

Comment: My expected output is the name of country in correct order of alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with h `distinct` and `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
y %>%
     distinct(jhu_ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
     arrange(jhu_ID)
```